# Why I try to run Client.jar on Another Computer but receive Connection refused" or "Connection timed out

Tags: java, rmi

I spent more than one day , but still can't figure out how can I resolve the problem. Every time I shut down the firewall on my server, my other computer can successfully run Client.jar.

I check the firewall on my server PC. I am sure I opened the port "4888" and "6151", but still can't run normally.

I don't know how "W.getSocketFactory()" works.

```
System.out.println("創造"+ W.getSocketFactory());  → 創造 null  (Is it an issue?)
```

Is there some problems on my codes or somethings?

Below is my server code:

```java
public class RemoteServer extends UnicastRemoteObject implements MyRemote{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try {
            RMILocalSocketFactory W = new RMILocalSocketFactory(6151);
            System.out.println("創造"+ W.getSocketFactory());
            RMISocketFactory.setSocketFactory(W);
            
            LocateRegistry.createRegistry(4888);
            System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname","175.183.49.139");
            MyRemote Server = new RemoteServer();           
            Naming.rebind("rmi://175.183.49.139:4888/Remote_Hello!", Server);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    RemoteServer() throws RemoteException {}
    
    public String SayHello() 
    {       
        System.out.println("RMI Connection");
        return "you Connected Server\n" + "Server says , Hey!";
    }
}
```

```java
class RMILocalSocketFactory extends RMISocketFactory {

    private int dataPort;
    
    public RMILocalSocketFactory(int dataPort1){
        this.dataPort = dataPort1;
    }

    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException {
        String a = "175.183.49.139";
        Socket check = new Socket(a = host, port);
        return check;
    }

    public ServerSocket createServerSocket(int port) throws IOException {   
        return new ServerSocket(port);
    } 
}
```

(Client) the one part of code:

````java
try {
    LocateRegistry.getRegistry(4888);
     
    MyRemote Service = (MyRemote)Naming.lookup("rmi://175.183.49.139:4888/Remote_Hello!");
    String Say= Service.SayHello();
    Area.append(Say);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```[Problem Picture:][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkK5T.jpg
````

Comment: If it works when the firewall is disabled, and stops working when the firewall is enabled, and that is the only difference, then this really seems to be some firewall setting that is the problem. Not something in your Java code.

Comment: What is `dataPort` for in your socket factory? And what is the point of `"175.183.49.139"`? You aren't using either of them. Your socket factory is doing nothing useful that the default wouldn't already do.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem by myself.

I finally found my java.exe on firewall is blocked.

That is the reason why I can't receive another request while firewall is on.

And make sure both port must be open on firewall as well.